# PostgreSQL: count or sum for every 1 hour interval

Tags: postgresql

Hello I am using this query which gives me the results shown in the picture:

```
SELECT "t_stamp", "Total_Parts"
FROM myTable
WHERE "MachineName" = 'Main01'
AND "Quality" is not NULL
AND t_stamp >= '2023-08-10 16:30:00' AND t_stamp <= '2023-08-14 00:30:00'
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

[image]

I wonder how can I get only the count for every hour... For example: I know I would have to sum the values from the Total_Parts column (in the red-box) but only for hour 17, and then the ones in the purple-box for the hour 18, and for the green-box for the hour 19.. Like the following table:

| t_stamp | Total_Parts |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-10 17:00 | 2,628 |
| 2023-08-10 18:00 | 2,016 |
| 2023-08-10 19:00 | 1,913 |

I was looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001149/how-to-get-count-for-every-1-hour-interval), but still could not figured it out.
Any help would be very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', t_stamp) AS t_stamp,
       SUM(Total_Parts)            AS Total_Parts
FROM myTable
WHERE "MachineName" = 'Main01'
      AND "Quality" IS NOT NULL
      AND t_stamp >= '2023-08-10 16:30:00'
      AND t_stamp <= '2023-08-14 00:30:00'
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', t_stamp)
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Oh, and, next time please add scripts for objects and data please :)

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your response. I honestly do not kow how to "add scripts for objects and data"... Can you please share how can start learning that. Thank you very much. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: You could create a script for the CREATE TABLE and INSERT data. For example through http://sqlfiddle.com/